# How to setup long running timers on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timer, scheduled-tasks, nstimer

I want to create a timer that should fire every hour. But from my research, an app gets suspended after 10 mins in the background. It also seems like the app gets suspended after the screen is locked.

I want to trigger this timer every 1 hour. I will be invalidating the timer when app goes in the background and restart it when the app foregrounds. So I have a few questions:

1. When the user backgrounds the app and comes back to it, will the timer fire immediately if it has been 1+ hour?
2. What happens if the user returns to the app after multiple (2+) hours, will the timer fire multiple times?

Are there any recommended ways to setup such longer running timers so they fire more consistently and not just once when they were setup?

Comment: Timers are not suitable for this use case _at all_. They are for controlling run loop execution, not for scheduling higher-level work, especially not directly related to UI and in such a distant future as 1 hour. What you are looking for is probably background tasks (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks), or local scheduled notification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Do you need the timer to trigger some action even if the app is in the background? Or do you only want the timer to run while in the foreground and have the timer suspended while in the background, picking up where it left off when returning to the foreground?

Comment: Common solution here is to grab a `Date` when the app is suspended, and compare it to the current date on launch. So you can run a timer for if the user remains in the app, and use date comparison if the leave and come back.

Comment: @akjndklskver I am not sure at the moment if I want it to still run when the app is back-grounded. Currently I am trying to evaluate my options. So what are my options if I wanted it to run only when the app comes back to background?

Comment: Did you mean to say "comes back _to_ background", or did you mean "comes back _from_ background"? in first case you need to react to react to `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` and use background tasks.

Comment: In second case, you need to react to `applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)` event and then you have multiple options. You can do scheduled notifications, or something more primitive like `DispatchQueue`'s `asyncAfter` or even just keeping the timestamp of "when was the last time I performed this operation" and run it if it's > 1 hour (because lets be honest: it's very unlikely that user actively actively uses your app for over 2 hours, so you may as well keep this work to start/ get to foreground).

Comment: Still though, getting timer is not a good option: it consumes resources, it's not reliable since it may be killed, and it just doesn't fit the whole purpose...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this without using background timer. It is only idea how you can achieve your requirement, add one or more hours condition as per your requirement.

```
var totalTime = Double()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

// MARK: - To Reset timer's sec if app is in background and foreground
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.background(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.foreground(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

 @objc func background(_ notification: Notification) {
   if self.totalTime > 0{
     user_default.setValue(self.totalTime, forKey: "TotalSecInBackground")
     user_default.setValue(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: "OldTimeStamp")
     LogInfo("total seconds left in background: \(self.totalTime)")
  }
}

  @objc func foreground(_ notification: Notification) {
   let timerValue: TimeInterval = user_default.value(forKey: "TotalSecInBackground") as? TimeInterval ?? 0
   let otpTimeStamp = user_default.value(forKey: "OldTimeStamp") as? TimeInterval ?? 0
   let timeDiff = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - otpTimeStamp
    if timerValue > timeDiff{
    LogInfo("total second & timeDiff:, \(Int(timerValue)),\(Int(timeDiff))")
    let timeLeft = timerValue - timeDiff
    self.totalTime = Int(timeLeft)
    LogInfo("timeLeft: \(Int(timeLeft))") // <- This is what you need
}}
```